# Does Lubuntu have a future?

Tags: lubuntu, release-management

I have some old, lower-end hardware (P4, 2.0 GHz, 1 GB RAM) onto which I have installed Lubuntu 13. 10 as my first venture into Linux. For the most part, everything has been fine and the learning curve hasn't yet been too bad to overcome.

The machine is mostly being used for web browsing and basic office type functions using LibreOffice.

After reading this post, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Testing/14.04, I'm wondering about the future of Lubuntu and whether I should stick with it. My plan for this particular machine was to upgrade it to Lubuntu 14.04 (hopefully it will released as a LTS version) and then give this machine to a relative who needs something for basic tasks.

Is it worth sticking with Lubuntu for something like this (a LTS release will probably outlive the machine's usefulness) or does it look like there isn't a future for Lubuntu and I should look into one of the other minimal distros.

Comment: Just so you know, Lubuntu has exactly the same future as Ubuntu, they are the same OS, they simply come with different default applications. There is no other significant difference between them.

Comment: Someone who feels that this question is opinion-based, are requested to atleast go through the link provided in question and then make a decision. The way that page is written can caste doubts in any new-comers mind.

Comment: @DKBose sure, but the point is that if the OP wants an OS that runs on older hardware, they can always install normal Ubuntu and use LXDE or XFCE or whatever as a DE, I was trying to point out that you don't need a different OS, just for a different GUI.

Comment: @DKBose I don't see why not. I've been using multiple DEs on the same distro for more than 10 years, that's the only reasonable way to do it. Installing a new OS to get a different DE is like using a tank to kill a fly.

Answer (score 7):

Lubuntu just started releasing LTS versions so why should the project end? As long as there is Ubuntu, there will be Lubuntu.
In fact, Lubuntu is Ubuntu, but uses the desktop environment LXDE and its software instead of the default DE called Unity.

Basically you can use every Linux system with the Xorg graphics server and install LXDE, which would look the same as Lubuntu, but would be have a bit differently.

Another lightweight environment would be XFCE (which is also available as [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org))

Basically you can choose any distro- and desktop-combo. But for an older PC you should stay with LXDE or XFCE.

Comment: Blackbox is very lightweight.. used it on a 486 about 8 years ago.